# Create a struct column from a map column preserving the data types

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, struct

I have the following script that creates a new struct column in my Pyspark dataframe based on a map (dictionary) column.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr

# Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# DataFrame with a map column
data = [(1, {"a": "10", "b": 20}), (2, {"x": 30, "y": True})]
columns = ["id", "map_column"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Distinct keys from the map column
distinct_keys = set([key for row in df.select("map_column").collect() for key in row["map_column"].keys()])

# Dynamic expression to create a struct with named columns
expressions = [expr(f"map_column.{key} as {key}") for key in distinct_keys]

# Add the dynamic expressions to the DataFrame
df = df.select("*", struct(*expressions).alias("struct_column"))
```

This code works very well, but all the columns of the struct column are being created as string type. How can I create the columns of the struct column respecting the original data type of the keys of the map column?